# How is the age for public folder calendar, task and contacts determined?

Tags: exchange-2016, public-folders

We are running Exchange 2016 on premise and the upper management wants to set an age limit for public folders.  We have a lot of public folders with tasks, contacts and calendar items.  How is the age limit (retention age) determined for these types of public folder items? There is a lot of information on how retention age is calculated for mailboxes but not for public folders.

Comment: Hi, any update? Please check if the answer below is helpful to you. If you problem has been fixed, you could mark the best answer or share your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There are two levels of age limits for public folder(**[Limits for public folders](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/collaboration/public-folders/limits?view=exchserver-2016)**):

1 **Organizational level**: Use the `DefaultPublicFolderAgeLimit` parameter on the `Set-OrganizationConfig` cmdlet.

[image]

And you could run the following command to view this setting:

**`Get-OrganizationConfig | fl DefaultPublicFolderAgeLimit`**

[image]

2 **Folder level**: Use the `AgeLimit` parameter on the `Set-PublicFolder` cmdlet.

[image]

Run the following command to view the age limit for single public folder:

**`Get-PublicFolder -GetChildren | Select Name, AgeLimit`**

---

There is another age limt for deleted items in public folder too:

[image]

---

Besides, you could also view the age limits of a public folder in EAC:

[image]

Comment: The above answer only covers how to set age limits on public folders.  What I wanted to know is if/when will contacts, reoccurring calendar items and tasks be deleted?  Is it based on the date created or the age after a calendar item and task is expired?  Will age limits delete contacts in public folders?